# modify a different index of list inside loop

Tags: arrays, list, loops, elixir

For modifying same index we can do

```
mylist = [1,2,3]    
Enum.map(mylist, fn x-> -x end) // [-1,-2,-3]
```

How would we modify a different index like

```
 for (i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {
     mylist[i+1] = -mylist[i];
 }
```

Comment: Sidenote: your pseudocode results in _JavaScript heap out of memory_ exception which crashes JS process entirely. That is mostly why we all hate mutating the objects.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to remember you have to create an entirely new list, so you should think about how best to get what you're looking for, not how to replicate how you would tackle it in another language.

If, for example, you're wanting to compare items with nearby items, you could zip a list with its offset:

```
iex> enum = 1..5
1..5
iex> stream = Stream.drop(enum, 1) # Enum.drop/2 would also work
#Stream<[enum: 1..5, funs: [#Function<48.15162342/1 in Stream.drop/2>]]>
iex> Enum.zip(enum, stream) # Stream.zip/2 works if you're going to iterate
[{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}]
```

For your specific example, where the next value is the previous value negated, you could create an infinite stream and take what you need:

```
iex> 1 |> Stream.iterate(&-/1) |> Enum.take(3)
[1, -1, 1]
```

If you're only looking to modify one value, you'll have to create a new list with only the new value changed (**NOTE** this is not the way you want to do several updates):

```
iex> {previous, [current | next]} = Enum.split(1..5, 3)
{[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]}
iex> Enum.concat([previous, [current * 12], next])
[1, 2, 3, 48, 5]
```

Comment: I'll upvote this as you took the time to explain why it's not a good idea to map imperative programming to functional. :thumbsup:

Comment: I would add Stream is inefficient for small lists, it shines best with with large lists and collections and as a higher level abstraction for reductions. Also, can you update your answer to include a recipe that results in the correct result?

Comment: Which correct result are you talking about? The only imperative code I see is the negation loop

Answer (score 1):

Both answers here so far are using Elixir core library helpers like `Enum.with_index/2`, or `Stream.iterate/2`, or `Enum.map/2`.

I am to show the barebone functional approach for modifying the neighbour index as in your pseudocode example. I will be replicating the snippet that does not crash the VM.

```
> mylist = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
> for (i = 1; i < mylist.length; i++) { mylist[i-1] = -mylist[i] }
> mylist
//⇒ [ -2, -3, 3 ]
```

In Elixir, using recursion, that would be:

```
defmodule Neighbour do
  def map(list, acc \\ [])
  def map([_, next | rest], acc), do: map(rest, [-next | acc])
  def map([next], acc), do: Enum.reverse([next, -next | acc])
end

Neighbour.map([1, 2, 3])
#⇒ [-2, -3, 3]
```

Comment: Upvoted because in this case a custom function vs higher order functions is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Remembering that data is immutable in Erlang and barring that it's not a good idea to map imperative programming to functional programming,  we could do something like the following:

```
new_list = Enum.map(Enum.with_index(list), fn {v,i} -> 
  ((Enum.at(list, i + 1) ||  0) - v) 
end)
```

Which is would result in `[1, 1, -3]` or in other words:

```
  2 - 1 = 1 
  3 - 2 = 1
  0 - 3 = -3
```

As others have pointed this would be an inefficient way to do such a thing per the O(n) complexity of Enum.at/2.

A more performant and idiomatic solution would be:

```
iex(1)> list0 = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> sliced = Enum.slice(list, 1, 2)  
[2,3]
iex(3) list2 = List.duplicate(0, length(list0) - length(sliced))
[2, 3, 0]
iex(21)> Enum.map(Enum.zip(list, list2), fn({v1, v2}) -> v2 - v1 end)
[1, 1, -3]
```

Comment: Just remember that `Enum.at/2` is O(n) complexity. So this would be really inefficient.

Comment: Indeed. I'll update the answer with something less cumbersome.